# How to extract ipa file from jail broken device

Tags: testing, jailbreak, ipa

I have a jailbroken iPhone 5s, and want to extract the `.ipa` file of one application that I have installed on that device. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Is it possible to extract the `.ipa` file from the iPhone without jailbreaking it? My intention is to perform static analysis of the application.

Comment: Without a jailbreak: If it's an App Store app, sync with iTunes to have them in iTunes' library folder. With a jailbreak: The IPA gets extracted and removed during install, but you can find the .app bundles in `/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/SOME-LONG-UUID/` on iOS 8 and `/var/containers/Bundle/Application/SOME-LONG-UUID/` on iOS 9. To easily find the folder of an App, use either an on-device file browser (e.g. Filza) or run `find . -name '*.app'` in the `Bundle/Applications` folder. Then use SSH with SFTP or scp to copy the files over.

Comment: which jailbreak and iOS version?  That dictates the answer.  `Filza`, `AppCake`, `iPAInstaller`, some Frida script, etc..

Answer (score 6):

Since you have a jailbroken iOS device, try installing `ipainstaller` from `Cydia` and then use `ipainstaller` to extract the app to an `.ipa` file.

I use `ipainstaller -l` to list all the apps installed on my jailbroken device and grab the bundle id of that app you wish to extract. Extract it using `ipainstaller -b <app_bundle>`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [IPA Installer](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.autopear.installipa/) from Cydia has not been updated since July 2016. That last version, 3.4.1-1, only supports up to iOS 9.

However, with [iMazing](https://imazing.com/), you can get something close. If you have previously "purchased"/downloaded an app from the Appstore, then are using the same Apple ID logged in to the Appstore, you can download it again. It appears that iMazing may be using the same Appstore API, so once you are logged in to the same Apple ID, you can download the ipa again. Except, this time, it would be downloaded to your Mac as an ipa, rather than iOS device. So it is technically not retrieving the ipa from the iOS device (it no longer exists in the device as an ipa anyway), but getting it from the Appstore. Then you can proceed with your static analysis.

Comment: While the IPA Installer's App no longer opens, I was able to use it's CLI as warfreak92 instructed to successfully create an ipa on iOS 14.8. I used NewTerm 2 from https://repo.chariz.com/ to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just tried, and indeed, the CLI of ipainstaller works even on iOS 14. However, were you able to install the IPA? It seems that the signing or some other integrity checks would be broken in such an IPA? I couldn't install the IPA, even after re-signing it. But I suppose it could be convenient and helpful for performing static analysis of the app.

Comment: Not sure; I have AppSync Unified on my device, so it doesn't require IPAs to be correctly signed. I backed them up hoping that re-signing them with eg https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign would be enough in the future.

As an aside, if you're just trying to get an older version of an app that's still on the app store, you could use AppStore++ to do that.